# C# import an excel column into ComboBox dropdown values

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, excel

I have a spread sheet with values that I would like to fill into drop down boxes in Windows forms using C#.  Some of these values contain 100's of entries and I don't want to fill them in by hand or embed them in the source code.

I also need to be able to add and remove values from the combo-box's once they are entered so I believe this rules out binding it to a data set.

How would one do this?

Comment: what have you tried thus far? what are you struggling with the combobox or the excel import?

Comment: I'm new to C# so not much.  I'm struggling to basically get a list of values(text document delimited by "\n") to fill a dropdown box in windows forms.  There are many values that need to be imported and I can't just physically make a list with all the values in the code.  So I thought that I could possible import these values from a XML document but this is blowing up in my face.  Basically just wondering if anyone has faced this problem before.

Comment: What is the "best practice" for getting many values into a combo-box?(say over 100 values)

Comment: I just ended up importing the combo box data from an XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excel library from this link http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/. There is actually an example code provided on this page, it demonstrates how to read from an excel file.

```
using ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet;

// open xls file
Workbook book = Workbook.Load(file);
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

// iterate with a proper condition, at the moment it will iterate with a given length!
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  comboBox.Items.Add(sheet.Cells[i,column_index].Value);
}
```

Just iterate through your excel column and add the elements to the combo-box. It is ok to add 100 but it won't be very clear.

If you don't want to hardcode your elements and have them as an external source, I'd recommend using an XML-format. It is easier to parse, much more clear and lightweight.

Comment: This didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

You mean input many values into combo-box?
If you get excel values into DataTable then insert value using foreach loop.

```
comboboxName.Items.Clear();
foreach(DataRow value in DataTableName.rows)
{
   comboboxName.Items.Add(value["ColumnName"]);
}
comboboxName.selectedIndex = 0;
```

If you struggling with excel import, then add comment to me again.

Comment: Yeah the excel import is probably the part I am most curious about.